# Aid with git bash commit error

Tags: git

I am trying to practice including git in projects but when I try to make a commit i get this error I am new and do not know what it is referring to or how to fix it.

> ```
> *** Please tell me who you are.
>
> Run
>
>   git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
>   git config --global user.name "Your Name"
>
> to set your account's default identity.
> Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.
>
> fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'john@LAPTOP-8GKLVF71.(none)')
> ```

Comment: The message tells you **exactly** what is wrong, and **exactly** what to do to fix it? Short of our coming to your desk and typing in the commands for you, what else do you expect us to do? That message is not there just to take up space on your screen;  it provides information, but only if you **actually read the words**. It explains (***Please tell me who you are***), and instructs you to **Run** a specific command *to set your account's default identity*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first install git, you have to set your user name and email address. Git uses these for commit messages etc.

If you carefully read the error, git is telling you what to do.

On the command line, run the following commands:

```
 git config --"your email address"  
 git config --"your name"
```

Comment: Thank you =) I do not know the terminology well.