# when i publish my app on github in android stduio through at that time i facing error

Tags: git, github

Successfully created project ‘MySample’ on GitHub, but initial commit failed Please tell me who you are.

Run

```
git config –global user.email “you@example.com” 
git config –global user.name “Your Name”
```

to set your account’s default identity.

Omit `–global` to set the identity only in this repository. fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got ‘home@home-PC.(none)’) during executing git commit -m “Initial commit"**`strong text`**

I have facing error when i shared

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aid with git bash commit error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47982598/aid-with-git-bash-commit-error)

Answer (score 0):

The error text is clear, Git requires author ID. You should open a Terminal and use the following commands (with your name and email):

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com" 
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

They will set up author ID for your commits.

After that you will be able to make first commit.

Comment: do not forget to upvote useful answers and accept the answer if it works for you